# How to Listen host url for detect active or inactive in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an mobile application . I have an rectangle on screen. If my host (www.myhost.com) is alive then rectange is green.But there is no connection to my host , then rectange is red.I have an AsycTask class for listening host continuously.My code is

```
    public class ServerPing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean isConnected = false;
    boolean isstop=false;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return isOnline();
    } 


    private  Void isOnline() {

        while (!isstop){
        try{
            // Thread.sleep(5000);
            URL url = new URL("http://myhost.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            // urlc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();

                if (urlc.getResponseCode()==200) {

                    if(!isConnected) {
                        isConnected=true;
                        ...Notify(true); // Notify Screen is green
                    } 



                } 

                else {
                    if(isConnected) 
                    {
                        isConnected=false;
                            ...Notify(false); // Notify Screen is red
                    }
                } 


            urlc.disconnect();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            if(isConnected) {
                isConnected=false;
                ...Notify(false); // Notify Screen is red
            }

        }  




    }
        return null;

    }




}
```

This code blocks well. But my question is ; This operation consume more CPU . Is there any proper way to detect server is active or inactive.

Comment: you can configure push notification type of things at your server which will send you notification whenever server is active or inactive

Comment: Google for android ping example , maybe usefull

Comment: Pinging a server will drain the battery quicker, just be aware of that. Push notifications may be better, but requires extra work on the server

Comment: @cricket_007 , I don't understand. If server is down , How to server push my tablet to notify , There is no access !!!

Comment: @Anjali , my comment is above , written to cricket_007

Comment: I just said it would require more work and wouldn't drain the battery as quickly. Didn't say it was perfect.